# Compiling Java using command line JAVAC

Tags: java

I'm kinda new to compiling using cmd line javac and I'm having trouble compiling this simple Base-Interface class

```
package com.apress.prospring2.ch03.di;

/**
 * @author janm
 */
public interface Encyclopedia {

    Long findLong(String entry);

}
```

---

```
package com.apress.prospring2.ch03.di;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * @author janm
 */
public class HardcodedEncyclopedia implements Encyclopedia {
    private Map<String, Long> entryValues = new HashMap<String, Long>();

    public HardcodedEncyclopedia() {
        this.entryValues.put("AgeOfUniverse", 13700000000L);
        this.entryValues.put("ConstantOfLife", 326190476L);
    }

    public Long findLong(String entry) {
        return this.entryValues.get(entry);
    }
}
```

I can easily compile Encyclopedia using javac Encyclopedia.java but when I try to compile HardcodedEncyclopedia .java I get

```
HardcodedEncyclopedia.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Encyclopedia
public class HardcodedEncyclopedia implements Encyclopedia {
                                              ^
1 error
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this without using Ant or Maven? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile you classes from the top level of your packages, so in this case, you need to be in the directory where the "com" sits.

Then you can do your compilation:

```
javac -cp . com/apress/prospring2/ch03/di/*.java
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're trying to compile `HardcodedEncyclopedia.java` from inside of the `com/apress/prospring2/ch03/di` directory. Even though `Encyclopedia.java` is in the same directory, javac needs to know how to find the `om.apress.prospring2.ch03.di` package its expected to be in. You can either specify the classpath like this:

```
javac -cp ../../../../.. HardcodedEncyclopedia.java
```

Or you can go to the root directory to imply the classpath as the current directory, like this:

```
cd ../../../../..
javac com/apress/prospring2/ch03/di/HardcodedEncyclopedia.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
javac Bar.java Foo.java
```

This is considering they are in the same package