# Packages in Java

Tags: java, package

It's my first time using packages in Java, and I'm not sure where I went wrong. I'm trying to make a Tetris game. Here's part of my code:

```
package mytetris;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Tetris extends JFrame {

    // class constructor
    public Tetris() {
        super("Tetris");
        this.setSize(400, 600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // just started, haven't really done anything

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tetris myTetris = new Tetris();
    }
}
```

I then compiled it using `javac Tetris.java` and then I tried running it using `java Tetris`, this is what the terminal gave me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Tetris (wrong name: mytetris/Tetris)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling Java using command line JAVAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926931/compiling-java-using-command-line-javac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have your file in /home/mytetris/Tetris.java

Then you need to run "java mytetris.Tetris" in the directory home.

Because you specified package mytetris, it will go to find your files in the directory mytetris, where it will find the class Tetris.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call it as

```
java mytetris.Tetris
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
java mytetris.Tetris
```

use fully qualified class name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following project structure:

```
project/src/mytetris/Tetris.java
project/classes
```

Run from the project dir:

```
javac src/mytetris/Tetris.java -d classes
```

It will compile Tetris.java and put it into classes dir.

Answer (score 0):

If you observe compilation code by the command javap your class name i.e

`javap Tetris` then it display it as

```
class mytetris.Tetris{

}
```

So when you execute this program ,you have to give command like this.

`java mytetris.Tetris` then your program executes smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the class mentioned in your program is not fount by JVM in the class loader. There are various reasons for this error.
check the detailed concept here https://te-xplore-ch.blogspot.com/2020/08/java-architecture.html
May be your package was not added in the source folder.
Click build path for the folder and click use as a source folder