# Access files in separate packages in Java

Tags: java, import

I am having trouble accessing a couple of classes in separate folders for a project I have in school. I am using Geany, and need to be able to have these classes talk to each other, so to speak.

There is one main folder in which all the separate packages are contained as their own folders, and within each folder there are all the classes specific to that package.

In my case, I need to be able to have some of the classes in a gameObjects package for use in a components package. I tried

```
import gameObjects.Room; 
import gameObjects.Entity;
```

but I get this compile error:

```
Position.java:3: error: package gameObjects does not exist
```

Is there any way to get these classes to talk to eachother? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The directory path looks like this:

```
C:\Users\matt\Desktop\New folder\Project
```

and in that Project folder are multiple folders where separate classes are contained. I need to be able to have two classes talk to each other from different folders within my Project folder.

I am compiling like so

```
C:\Users\matt\Desktop\New folder\Project\components>javac Position.java
```

EDIT #2: Both the Room and Entity classes are contained in a folder/package called gameObjects, and they, along with every other class in that folder contains

```
package gameObjects;
```

as its first line.

Comment: Please post the directory structure with files.

Comment: What is the **first line** of `Room`?

Comment: How are you compiling/running?

Comment: We'll need both the directory structure, and the compile line along with all its options.  Please also specify what directory you are compiling from.

Comment: Putting `.java` files into the same folder is not equal to specifying the same package for them. Also, putting `.java` files into any folder doesn't mean that you've contained these files in any package. To make sure these files are in package, the first line of these files (not taking comments into account) should be `package yourPackageName;`

Comment: Some info on the command line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926931/compiling-java-using-command-line-javac

Comment: I really don't get it what is the reason of asking any question here and not providing further explanations in comments or edits to question when asked for it... :-/

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal  I was in a class, my apologies. I have posted edits

Comment: @DaveNewton I have posted edits as to how im compiling

Comment: @markspace I have posted an edit as to how i am compiling

Comment: Try compiling like this: `C:\Users\matt\Desktop\New folder\Project>javac components\Position.java` -- the directory you're in matters.

Comment: You need to show your complete directory structure, where you're running from and how, etc. You're doing something fundamentally wrong, and whatever it is it's trivial, but we need complete details.

Comment: @DaveNewton See the comment above yours, he solved it for me :)

Comment: My point was that without complete information we're just guessing. When you ask questions you need to provide everything necessary to answer it-in the context of Java compilation/execution problems that boils down to directory structure, compilation command, execution command, and the directory you're running stuff from.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you not see my edit? I posted the complete directory path as well as the command I was using to compile. Sorry if I seem rude, but the information is there. Probably why he was able to solve my problem.

Comment: @MattyS11 Yes, I did--and yes, you're being rude. My previous two comments were not a comment on the edited question, but information regarding how to ask questions on SO: without complete information from the beginning it's a bunch of noise back-and-forth when it could have been answered trivially and quickly from a single post.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay man, well I know for next time. Sorry I made the original mistake. I will be sure to be more specific next time.

Comment: @MattyS11 It's no big deal, just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> I am having trouble accessing a couple of classes in separate folders
>   for a project

Folder basically are packages. So class Room and Entity cannot be in different folders because as you wrote:

> import gameObjects.Room;
>   import gameObjects.Entity;

These classes should be in "gameObjects" folder/package. So I guess the structure of your project is wrong. If you want to keep them in different folders then it will have different package.

> Position.java:3: error: package gameObjects does not exist

Put both classes in gameObjects folder then add in the first line of each file "package gameObjects;"

Comment: Room and Entity are in gameObjects. Sorry if I didnt make this clear. What I am trying to do is import those classes and use them in the components package.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `.java` files in separate folder in explorer doesn't mean that you specify **any** package for them. To have an ability to import classes, you need to make sure that you specify a **package** for them. You achieve it with putting:

```
package gameObjects;
```

line at the very beginning of the proper `.java` file. After specifying that package, you can import classes contained in that package with:

```
import gameObjects.nameOfClass;
```

Note that if you don't specify a `package` at the beginning of `.java` file, it's then contained in *default* package (you have access to classes contained in *default* package only from other classes contained in *default* package too). You can't import classes that don't have a `package nameOfYourPackage;` statement at the very beginning of `.java` file, so you can't use them outside of *default* package.

Note that Java takes care of putting `.java` files into specific folders on your hard drive on its own. So, when you specify that your `sample.java` file is contained in `yourpackage`, there is a folder named `yourpackage` created in your project directory and `sample.java` is put into that folder.

Comment: So Room and Entity both have to have that package gameObjects; at the start of the file in order to import them? Because they both still do. The very first line of every file in the gameObjects package is: package gameObjects;

Comment: Yes, if you want to import both classes with `import gameObjects.Room;` and `import gameObjects.Entity;`, you need to put the following line at the very beginning of `Room.java` and `Entity.java`: `package gameObjects;`

Comment: If you want to import all classes contained in `gameObjects` package, you might want to consider using shortcut: `import gameObjects.*;` - with that line you simply import all classes contained in `gameObjects` package and don't need to write 2 separate `import ...` lines.

Comment: So they both have that at the beginning of the file , but the import is still causing the same compile error :( saying the package gameObjects does not exist.

Comment: Yes, both (if you want to import both and if you want both to be contained in the same package). Did you save your files after adding these lines?

Comment: @MattyS11 Do you use some IDE to create your program?